# Is there a maven plugin or mojo to build IntelliJ IDEA plugins

Tags: plugins, maven, intellij-idea

I'd like to use Maven to build an IntelliJ IDEA plugin. Googling and searching SO has failed me. Can anyone tell me if there is a such a Maven plugin?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think you need a dedicated one. A plugin is just a jar with a particular file descriptor. Nothing the standard plugins can't produce.

Comment: Thanks, that's encouraging. One useful advantage of a dedicated plugin would be to draw in all the IntelliJ SDK dependencies. So I'm still hoping there's something ready-rolled out there.

Comment: That's more an archetype sort of thing, not that I'm seeing any of those either. I imagine the library licensing issues are playing a role in keeping these things private.

Answer (score 6):

If you're still interested in using Maven for IntelliJ plugin development, here's how we implemented at our company : http://labs.bsb.com/2013/11/how-to-manage-development-life-cycle-of-intellij-plugins-with-maven-2/